# Testing the assumptions of null models when using likelihood ratio tests to compare mixed-effect models

Tags: r, mixed-model, assumptions, lme4-nlme, overdispersion

I have ran a Generalized mixed-effect model using the glmer function in the lme4 package. To appraise the significance of the model, I am using a likelihood ratio test. For example, if testing the 'explanatory' variable:

```
Full_model <- glmer(Response ~ Explanatory + (1|Subject), data = df, family = "poisson")
Null_model <- glmer(Response ~ 1 + (1|Subject), data = df, family = "poisson")
anova(Null_model,Full_model)
```

What is the protocol for examining the assumptions of the null model if the full model checks out OK (in terms of under or overdispersion, homogeneity etc)? With my own data, I found that the latter was overdispersed, but I am also interested to know as to how this extends to examining the spread of variances within the model. Any thoughts and inputs on this would be greatly appreciated.